# union along with a where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to do something like this, but I know that this would lead to error

```
select * from t1 a
union 
select * from t2 b
union 
select * from t3 c
where b.col1!=c.col1
```

What should I be using in order to achieve above?..

Thanks !!

Comment: What do you want to do? Some sample inputs/outputs might be helpful. As is, I can't see how you intend for that to work; if you're unioning all the rows of a, b, and c into one list, it doesn't really make sense to talk about row-wise comparisons of b and c as though they were joined together.

Comment: Thanks @forpas, that was exactly what I needed, thanks a lot, both answers work great!!

Comment: Thanks @Yogesh Sharma, that was exactly what I needed, thanks a lot, both answers work great!!

Comment: @pc_pyr is there a reason that you chose to accept the latest answer?

Comment: Your code works well @forpas, and that I'm using union all for duplicates! And I have upvoted your answer too ! Thanks again!

Comment: Your code uses UNION this is why I also used UNION. So what else is there that makes my answer different?

Comment: Also I'm using `aliases`! Now I have just upvoted alone, on both the answers so that it's balanced on both the answers @forpas

Comment: You don't need the aliases in this case because none of the 3 unioned queries can access the others (they are out of scope). What do you mean by balanced? There is nothing balanced when you choose to accept the answer that was posted later.

Comment: The reason I used aliases here is, it would be required that I need to mention the column names explicitly since the order of columns are different in all the 3 tables, hope it's fine on why I am using aliases and I am also accepting your answer, don't have a problem with that, thanks @forpas!

Comment: The requirements to use UNION ALL instead of UNION or aliases do not exist anywhere in your question. Your question is *how can I make this work?*. So the answer is based just on this. If you have other requirements too then they should be mentioned.

Comment: As and how `union` is used instead of `union all`, thought `aliases` would also be used consecutively in the answer, in continuation with how it's posted in question. Anyways, would do that in future @forepas

Comment: Hope you noticed your accepted answer, thank you @forpas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you want `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select * from t1
union 
select * from t2
union 
select * from t3
where not exists (
  select 1 from t2
  where t2.col1 = t3.col1
)
```

With this query `t3`'s rows will be included in the final result only if the value of `col1` does not exist also in any of `t2`'s rows.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `exists` :

```
select a.col1, a.col2, . . .
from t1 a union all
select b.col1, b.col2, . . .
from t2 b union all
select c.col1, c.col2, . . .
from t3 c
where not exists (select 1 from t2 b where c.col1 = b.col1);
```

Note : Use explicit column name in `union all`.